# Network scanner server not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: scanner

How to configure a usb scanner which is working on a desktop as a network scanner using saned in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Have you read `man saned`? Which parts of `man saned` do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late... I hope it helps:

Tutorial from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaneDaemonTutorial works fine however you NEED to install libsystemd-dev in order to make it work.

```
sudo apt install libsystemd-dev
```

After that just reboot your server and pre-configured clients will be able to do

```
scanimage -L
```

By the way, if "sudo service saned status" at your server says something like:

```
● saned.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Just ignore it since Saned service only starts by request from Sane clients

Regards